# how can I create a function with throw and return a value in swift?

Tags: swift

I am new on swift. I try to understand the function with throw. is it possible to make the function throw and at the same function return a value?

```
func throwAndReturnString() {
    guard let response = internalFunction else {
        throw "response should not nil"
    } 
    return response.label
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to `throw` and `return` simultaneously? Your question seems ambiguous. If so, no you can't do that. For throwing in general, you may want to check out the documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/errorhandling/

Answer (score 1):

To have a function that can `throw` it needs to be decorated with `throws` and to `return` the type needs to be added to the signature.

```
func throwAndReturnString() throws -> String { //<<--HERE
```

This assumes that `label` is a `String`